# Is there a way to select a zip file for opening using storage access framework?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I have an app which allows the user to export and or import bulk data either through a CSV or a zipped-up bundle containing multiple files.

At present it uses a third-party library (ar.com.daidalos.afiledialog) but I'm trying to migrate to the Storage Access Framework, which users are more likely to be familiar with (and also looks more "android-y"). The current library can't use Drive, which is extra functionality I'd like to add.

I've got it working so that exports to both formats work. And I can choose a CSV file to read using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("text/*");
startActivityForResult(intent,4);
```

But when I change the type to "application/zip" (or anything looser, for that matter) in order to make the zip selectable, the file chooser treats the zipfile as another directory and displays its contents rather than picking it. It would appear that it's responding to the .zip extension, as when I remove it from the file it makes it selectable (which may give me a workaround if I can't solve this properly).

So the question is, how do I tell the chooser to **pick** the zipfile rather than descending into it? I *have* to use a zipfile, because existing users already have data exported in that format which they may need to read.

Comment: To be clear... if you use `intent.setType("application/zip")`, and you navigate to a `.zip` file in the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` UI... that UI navigates into the ZIP file?

Comment: Correct. In fact, *whatever* type I choose which is valid for selecting the zip file (ie, not text types), it navigates into the zip.

Comment: Hmmm... what device(s) are you testing on? I just tried this on Android 8.1 on a Pixel 2. I do not get the navigate-into-the-ZIP behavior when using `intent.setType("application/zip");`. It selects the ZIP and the `Uri` that I get back would appear to point to the ZIP file. I have tried ZIP files in both the root of external storage and in the `Downloads/` directory on external storage. I also tried it on a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 running Android 5.0, with the same results.

Comment: Ah! The penny drops. I've been testing on a Genymotion VM. As soon as I try it on a real device it behaves correctly. So the bug is in Genymotion.

Comment: Also, I was working on a "real device" and was requesting "text/zip".  Files were visible but not selectable. As @commonsware pointed out, you need "application/zip" to select -- at least on android 10.

Comment: @CommonsWare I found this happen on some official emulators too: API 24 Google Play, API 25. API 21-23 and 26 onwards is fine.

Answer (score 1):

For reference if anyone has this problem in future, this has been "solved" due to CommonsWare's comment. The problem only seems to occur on a Genymotion emulator. On a real device it works as I hoped.

Comment: It still happens on physical devices running android 7.